# Android: Activity that close your antecessor

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two Activities, "A" and "B", which "A" opens "B". When the user hits the back button on the Activity "B", i don´t want to see "A", i just want to close "A". So on the "B" i did this:

```
@Override
    public void finish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class).putExtra(TAG, TAG).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);                                              
        startActivity(intent);
        //super.finish();
    }
```

And in the Activity "A", i did this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         

         if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
             if(getIntent().getStringExtra(HomeActivity.TAG) != "")
                 finish();              

    }
```

It works perfectly, but i´m getting this Exception:

```
E/ActivityThread(11115): Activity br.com.pedmobiledroid.view.controller.LoginActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$1@42045be0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

Someone does know the better way to do this properly?

Comment: I have two question.Are you using receiver inside Any Activity? And second, Why do you finish A while launching B, if you want it to finish on finishing of B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `finish()` on `ActivityA` after starting `ActivityB`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: @Egor I thought that finish() doesn't get executed.Isn't a new activity already launched before the control hits finish()

Comment: @erickles, ActivityA will still have to finish before ActivityB starts, so the finish() will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to reorder the logic you have.

Instead of killing activity A when coming from Activity B, simply kill Activity A if it's going to Activity B. That way, it won't be on the backstack when the user presses back :)

So, from A:

```
Intent startActivityBIntent = new Intent(this, MyClassB.class);
startActivity(startActivityBIntent);
this.finish();
```

And that's it, no code is required on Activity B, since A already finished itself.